# Property evalution failed ERROR while Exporting Gridview to Excel

Tags: vb.net, gridview, export-to-excel

I am trying to export gridview data to Excel.

But I am getting error `Property Evaluation Failed` at `Response.End()`

This is my code - any ideas?

```
Private Sub ExportGridToExcel()
Try
Response.Clear()
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=NPS.xls")
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
' Remove the charset from the Content-Type header.
Response.Charset = ""

' Turn off the view state.
Me.EnableViewState = False

Dim tw As New System.IO.StringWriter()
Dim hw As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw)

' Get the HTML for the control.
gvNPSResults.RenderControl(hw)
' Write the HTML back to the browser.
Response.Write(tw.ToString())
' End the response.

HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
Response.End()
Catch ex As Exception
'Throw ex
End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try once again replacing your code

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

Response.End();
```

by

```
 Response.Flush();
 Response.Close();
```